# What is the easiest way to split a set of double quote delimited name-value pairs into an array?

Tags: vba, excel

Given a string containing:

```
property myprop1="test" myprop2="testing again" myprop3="another test"
```

What is the easiest way to get into a string array:

```
property
myprop1="test"
myprop2="testing again"
myprop3="another test"
```

Splitting into a 2 dimension array would be even better:

```
property
myprop1     test
myprop2     testing again
myprop3     another test
```

My original plan was to run the split function with a space delimiter on the string.  This works if there are no spaces embedded in the value portion of the name-value pair, which (of course) do contain spaces.

Some conditions:
This code needs to execute in Excel 2010 VBA.  I don't want to have to add third-party references or a bunch of toolkits.  I'm not looking for elegant or IEEE examples.  I need maintainable and understandable production code.

Thanks in advance for any and all assistance!

EDIT: The number of 'mypropX' are variable; there may be less or more than three.
EDIT2: I've been informed of another 'difference'. :)  Turns out the value of a myprop might not be delimited by double quotes; in that case it will be a single alphanumeric string with no interior spaces.

Comment: Would the pattern of the string always remain the same? As in, it would have `property <text>`?

Comment: It would always be: <string> <string>="<string>" <string>="<string>"...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I came up with.  It's not elegant but it gets the job done.  Thanks for the input folks, it was very helpful.

```
'split name value pairs into array
strWorkString = schematicLines(lngValuePosition)
lngStartPosition = 1
lngEndPosition = 1
fStartQuote = False
f1stWordDone = False
ReDim strWorkArray(0) As String

For lngLoopCounter = 1 To Len(strWorkString) - 1

    strCurrentCharacter = Mid(strWorkString, lngLoopCounter, 1)

    Select Case True
        Case (strCurrentCharacter = " " And Not fStartQuote)   'space and we aren't in a value
            If (f1stWordDone) Then
                ReDim Preserve strWorkArray(UBound(strWorkArray) + 1) As String
            End If

            lngEndPosition = lngLoopCounter
            strWorkArray(UBound(strWorkArray)) = Trim(Mid(strWorkString, lngStartPosition, lngEndPosition - lngStartPosition))
            lngStartPosition = lngEndPosition + 1
            lngEndPosition = lngStartPosition
            f1stWordDone = True

        Case strCurrentCharacter = Chr$(34) 'double quote

            If fStartQuote Then   'in a value
                'store the nvp
                lngEndPosition = lngLoopCounter

                ReDim Preserve strWorkArray(UBound(strWorkArray) + 1) As String
                strWorkArray(UBound(strWorkArray)) = Trim(Mid(strWorkString, lngStartPosition, lngEndPosition - lngStartPosition + 1))

                lngLoopCounter = lngLoopCounter + 1 'skip the space
                lngStartPosition = lngLoopCounter
                lngEndPosition = lngStartPosition

                fStartQuote = False
            Else
                fStartQuote = True
            End If
    End Select

Next lngLoopCounter

' get the last nvp
ReDim Preserve strWorkArray(UBound(strWorkArray) + 1) As String
strWorkArray(UBound(strWorkArray)) = Mid(strWorkString, lngStartPosition, lngLoopCounter - lngStartPosition + 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you replace('="','=') then you can do a split on '" ' and this should give you:

```
property
myprop1=test
myprop2=testing again
myprop3=another test
```

This assumes that there are no " inside the quotes (which would make a mess of most attempts to parse anyway).

Then you can split the items in this array on '=' to get into a 2 element array. To account for possible = within values set the Limit parameter on Split() to 2.

Edit:
I'm feeling generous - here's some code - add your own error handling!

```
Public Sub ParseNVPs(ByVal str As String, ByRef ReturnArray() as String)
Dim SplitArray() As String
Dim LineArray() As String
Dim i As Integer

    str = Replace(str, "=""", "=")
    SplitArray = Split(str, """ ")

    ReDim ReturnArray(UBound(SplitArray), 1)

    For i = 0 To UBound(SplitArray)
        LineArray = Split(SplitArray(i), "=", 2)
        ReturnArray(i, 0) = LineArray(0)
        ReturnArray(i, 1) = LineArray(1)
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: (Put in the asterisks to try and show line breaks) This is giving me: ****Property myprop1=test ****myprop2=testing again ****myprop3=another test myprop4=another test myprop5=another test ****I didn't note that there could be more than three properties; I've updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Sub Test()
    Dim strVar, Arr1, Arr2()

    strVar = "property myprop1=""test"" myprop2=""testing again"" myprop3=""another test"""

    Arr1 = Split(Mid(strVar, InStr(1, strVar, " ") + 1), """ ")
    ReDim Arr2(UBound(Arr1) + 1)
    Arr2(0) = Mid(strVar, 1, InStr(1, strVar, " ")) 'store the first string, i.e. property

    'store the data with double quotes
    For i = 0 To UBound(Arr1) - 1
        Arr2(i + 1) = Arr1(i) & """"
    Next
    'store the last string
    Arr2(i + 1) = Arr1(i)

    For i = 0 To UBound(Arr2)
        MsgBox Arr2(i)
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: This answer also assumes three properties; I've updated the original question.

Comment: @Falconeer - In my answer, you can have as many properties as you want. The first word needs to be property.

Comment: It's putting the third and all following NVPs in the last element of a 4 element array.

Comment: @Falconeer - Doesn't do it on my machine though. I tried with 4+ elements ... `strVar = "property myprop1=""test"" myprop2=""testing again"" myprop3=""test again more"" myprop4=""more test"" myprop5=""again test"""` ... worked for me.